# Add CDN links for libraries in tags wikis, which can be options to add into stack snippets

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-snippets, tag-wiki

For JavaScript and CSS libraries that have tags, CDN links could be added to the tag wiki for different versions of the libraries (I'm assuming the wiki is the best place).
Then, when a code snippet is started, those libraries could be offered as "external resource" options.

This would solve some of the problems with which libraries to add on the side; you could  reduce it down to just jQuery, and the rest would be dependent on the tags added to the question.